# view contents of directory in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know how to view the contents of a directory in gcloud.
I ran

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-west1-b cs231-vm
```

from powershell and connected to my instance.

I am trying to navigate to like this:

```
cd cs231n/datasets
```

according to a tutorial here:
http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2018/assignment1/
But it says no such file or directory and so I want to know what is in the current directory. I tried ls and dir but get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` or `dir` definitely works on gcloud, it seems probably you might have missed few steps of downloading folder/data. Please see if you have completed **First time setup** from http://cs231n.github.io/gce-tutorial/

You can also 'view gcloud command' by clicking ssh dropdown available at list of vm-instances page. Additionally you can pass `--project='project-name'` to your gcloud ssh command.